# Restart IIS AppDomain on type initializer/static constructor exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, exception

I've got an ASP.NET that relies on some code that uses static constructors. The code in these type initializers sometimes fails. Let's say, for sake of argument, that the code is:

```
public static readonly string Thing = SomeSpecialCallThatRarelyFails();
```

Perhaps that's vile, but it cannot be changed. And this kinda code is in every controller, so ASP.NET can't create the controller and just sits there broken until someone comes along to restart it.

I understand this is the way it should be, because the problem may very well be non-transient and auto-restarting would create a loop. Or perhaps only one controller fails, so the app is still sort of alive. So I get the default behaviour to just keep returning the error. But in this particular case, let's pretend the best thing is to notice this failure and restart.

How can I automate the detection of this scenario and trigger a restart or recycle of the IIS app pool/AppDomain?

I've noticed that if I cause an exception on Application_Start, then the app will auto-restart. So one way is for me to iterate over all my types and try accessing them. If they have .cctor failures, then I'll crash Application_Start and ASP.NET will restart. But that's pretty hacky, plus it won't help if the actual request code references another type that I don't know about which throws on .cctor.

Is there a better way? Should I write a Web API filter and look for TypeInitializerException or something?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought. Is the 'rare failure' deterministic? Could it be solved by adding retry logic?

```
public static readonly string Thing = RetrySpecialCall();

private static string RetrySpecialCall()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return SomeSpecialCallThatRarelyFails();
        }
        catch (Exception) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid modifying any of the client code, and solve it instead by doing something global to ASP.NET/Web API.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a way to handle it in Web API 1:

In Application_Start, iterate over your controller types, calling System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor to force all your known type constructors to run. If it Application_Start fails, ASP.NET seems to restart.

Add an exception filter that looks for TypeInitializationExceptions. Then call HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain().

The two parts are needed as a controller failing to construct will not hit the exception filters.

With Web API 2 it seems like you could do it in [one go](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) by implementing System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionLogger and registering it as a global service. Same logic: check for TypeInitializationException and UnloadAppDomain if so.